# Element Tree, Parsing XML didnt appear in QLineEdit

Tags: python, xpath, xml-namespaces, elementtree

i make plugin in QGIS to open and parse xml from local disk or removable disk, this is code i use to open xml file :

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
from ui_testparse import Ui_testparse
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ETree
# create the dialog for zoom to point


class testparseDialog(QtGui.QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        QtGui.QDialog.__init__(self)
        # Set up the user interface from Designer.
        self.ui = Ui_testparse()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)

        opendata = self.ui.btnCari
        QtCore.QObject.connect(opendata, QtCore.SIGNAL('clicked()'),self.openxml)

    def openxml(self, event=None):

        #open dialog
        openfile = QtGui.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, 'Open File', '*.xml')

        self.ui.lineLokasi.setText(openfile)

        #call XML data
        self.isiData(openfile)

    def isiData(self, nmsatu):
        #open teks with read mode
        openteks = open(nmsatu, 'r').read()

        self.ui.textXml.setText(openteks)
```

and to parse xml after that i try use Element Tree, this code i use to parse xml from code above :

```
#Parse XML from Above
        self.parsenow(openteks)

    def parsenow(self, parse):
        element = ETree.fromstring(parse)
        xml_obj = ETree.ElementTree(element)
        for title_obj in xml_obj.findall('./{gmd#}dateStamp/{gco#}Date'):
            print element
            self.ui.lineSkala.setText(element)
```

and xml i want to parse have format like this :

```
<gmd:datestamp>
<gco:Date> XML Date </gco:Date>
```

i try to show *XML Date* in LineSkala(lineEdit) in QT but when i run it, it can open and read xml but failed to show *XML Date* in lineSkala, it just blank and didn't give me any error message

What i miss? 
Thanks for your help in advance

Answer (score 2):

The [XPath syntax supported by etree](https://docs.python.org/release/2.7.6/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#supported-xpath-syntax) is quite limited. Also, you must either supply a prefix dictionary when using [find/findall](https://docs.python.org/release/2.7.6/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.Element.find) (although this is not properly documented in python2), or use the full namespace uri.

So try something like:

```
ns = {
    'gmd': 'http://www.isotc211.org/2005/gmd',
    'gco': 'http://www.isotc211.org/2005/gco',
    }

tree.findall('.//gmd:dateStamp/gco:Date', ns)
```

or:

```
tree.findall('.//{http://www.isotc211.org/2005/gmd}dateStamp/'
             '{http://www.isotc211.org/2005/gco}Date')
```

PS:

If you need to use more sophisticated XPath syntax, try [lxml](http://lxml.de/), which has a very similar API to ElementTree, but many more features.